# How to handle events in ng-repeat without using onclick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I'm currently building a chrome extension. Chrome's policy is that inline JS event handlers are not allowed, so I'm looking for a way to create event listeners for my ng-repeat elements.

I've tried just generating the event handlers based on the dataset that I'm passing to ng-repeat, and since I know the template I've been able to generate the appropriate IDs, but I can't seem to get the timing right so that the event listeners are set only after ng-repeat has finished updating the DOM.

My current code is below:

```
app.controller('commentsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = datalayer;
    //console.log($scope.data);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

            for (var i = 0; i < datalayer.comments.length; i++){
                var id = datalayer.comments[i].id + "_replybutton";
                console.log(id);
                var div = document.getElementById(id);
                console.log(div);
                console.log(datalayer.sc);
            }

        });

    });
```

x_replybutton is the id format for the button I want to create listeners for. Currently I can get the above code to work fine in the console once the repeated section is loaded, but it doesn't run when I add it to the controller.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently ng-click is permitted by the chrome security policy. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/angular_framework

Answer (score 2):

Where is your `datalayer` variable coming from? You should not use
global variables inside controllers or services, but inject what you need.

I would guess `datalayer` does not have a value when you set assign it to `$scope.data`,
but is rather a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
that is resolved at some point, probably made by
[$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) somewhere?

If that is the case, (ignoring for now that you should produce the value in an injected Service)
you can probably do

```
app.controller('commentsCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    datalayer.then((datalayer) => {
        $scope.data = datalayer;
        $timeout(()=>{
            for (var i = 0; i < datalayer.comments.length; i++){
                var id = datalayer.comments[i].id + "_replybutton";
                var div = document.getElementById(id);
                div.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    console.log('clicked');
                });
            }
        }, 0);
    })
}
```

`$timeout(()=>{ <code here> }, 0)` will make your code await execution until Angular has finished
rendering the DOM (actually makes JavaScript execute the code after the stack is clear).

Comment: Awesome point about the timeout thanks. The datalayer is just a placeholder at the moment for an xhr req but I'll take that into consideration as well.